# one folder not uploaded in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I am having some problems with bitbucket. All my project folders and files are uploaded except the src folder. The src folder in my computer has files and folders. But it is not appearing in bitbucket. Why is the src folder appearing like that in bitbucket?

[image]

I enter the commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit of full repository"
git remote add origin
https://boidurja@bitbucket.org/boidurja/kapstone.git
```

and I get this error:

```
F:\BOP consultancy and services\vuetify project\kapstoneui>git remote add 
origin
 https://boidurja@bitbucket.org/boidurja/kapstone.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

And I enter this command:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

and I get this error:

```
F:\BOP consultancy and services\vuetify project\kapstoneui>git push -u 
origin --all
To https://bitbucket.org/boidurja2/kapstone.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://boidurja2@bitbucket.org/boidurja2/kapstone.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The information is in the error message. You should `git pull` before pushing, because the server's repo has updated version of the code.

Comment: @vicodin Thanks for commenting. But how do I git pull? What options should I give?

Comment: just type `git pull` in a terminal

Comment: I just typed git pull in a terminal. I got this: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master